# How to use Django template custom variable, like forloop.counter and use to judge

Tags: django

I want to set a auto_increment variable for some judge,but I found

```
forloop.counter
```

can't be use like this

```
<ul class="listcont2">
{% for item in lists%}
{%if forloop.counter%6==0 && forloop.counter<12 %}
    <li><a  ><img  /></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="listcont2">
{%else%}
    <li><a  ><img  /></a></li>
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
</ul>
```

Is there anyway to set a custom  auto_increment variable ?

Comment: I think you're using the word judge to mean something else. What about `forloop.counter` are you trying to customize? What, in your custom implementation, would behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) instead of the modulus, and [`and`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators) instead of `&&`:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"6" and forloop.counter < 12 %}
```

Comment: However, after looking at the above logic, wouldn't it be equivalent to write: `{% if forloop.counter == 6 %}`?

Comment: Thank you! That's great!